# Spring 3.2 properties issue with @Value

Tags: java, spring

I've searched stackoverflow, read docs and can not seem to get my @Value("${myproperty.value}") to give me anything other than null.

I have some beans that I have defined in my spring-servlet.xml as well the properties file.

```
<!-- Load properties files  -->
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:MyProperties.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true" />
```

The properties file gets loaded without errors. In the same xml I have defined a bean.

```
<bean id="pushNotification"  class="com.mydomian.actions.MyClass"/>
```

In the bean I have properties that use the @Value.

```
private @Value("${some.property}") String propertyValue;
```

My properties are always null.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare

```
<context:annotation-config />
```

to enable annotation processing.

Comment: @Michael Show us your full context.

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by showing the full context?

Comment: @Michael You've shown two configuration elements from your context configuration, namely a `<bean>` declaration and a `<property-placeholder>` declaration. I want to see all of it. I'd also like to see how you load the context and how you retrieve the bean.

Comment: Adding the entire XML config, isn't easy to do as there is security config and other sensitive info in there. If there is something more specific that I can post a larger block I would be happy to. Is there something else that could be missing other than what you mentioned above? The push notification bean is beam is being autowired.

Comment: @Michael Here's the dirty. If annotation config and property resolution is enabled, Spring **can and will not** inject `null`. It's (pretty much) impossible. If it's `null`, either the configs are not enabled or are enabled in the wrong context files. Remember, both of these configurations only apply to the contexts they are defined in. The other possibility is that you aren't looking at the fields of instances managed by Spring (beans), but rather objects you created yourself.

Comment: I changed the config of the app to use the Spring created beans by using @Autowired. Is there a way to tell what context those beans my have been created in? It is possible that it is in the wrong context, but I have had some trouble in trying to find the best way to determine that.

Comment: @Michael Is your `pushNotification` bean declared in the context that also declares the annotation config and property placeholder?

Comment: Yes, it is beaning declared in the same context.

Comment: @Michael Next thing to check: is it a bean or just an object you created? How do you see that it is `null`? Do you get a `NullPointerException`? If so, let's see the stacktrace.

Comment: No NullPointerException just all @Value are null when debugging and inspecting the values. So there are no exceptions, everything appears to load correctly. The only beans being used are autowired.

Comment: @Michael Where is the `pushNotification` bean used? Show us where it is injected and used.